# How to deal with EF Core database migration failures?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

During startup I want to run the database migrations. This sample implementation runs on startup

```
class DatabaseMigrationService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    
    public DatabaseMigrationService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using IServiceScope serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        DatabaseContext databaseContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
        
        await databaseContext.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

but what if something fails while running the migrations? I am not sure what the correct strategy for failure handling is but I would expect the following workflow:

- perform a migration roll back
- throw the exception
- let the application crash because there is no reason to continue

How can I secure that running the `StartAsync` method won't destroy databases on errors? What to do in the catch statement when wrapping the `MigrateAsync` method into a try/catch statement?

Comment: I'd run it in Program.cs and not in a hosted service. Request services from the host after you build it but before you call run on it. Then at least your program will fail during the startup phase and you'll know about it

Comment: Do not run migrations during startup, generate a script and run during deployment

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 so you mean making the `Main` method async and use this sample code? `            IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            await host.RunMigrations();
            host.RunAsync();`

Comment: @ErikEJ I'm generating migrations like so `dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration ...` how can I run migrations in a single transaction script during deployment then?

Comment: Yeah.. Basically. You'd need `using var scope = host.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope()` instead of the first line you have in your current StartAsync method. Though I do agree you should run migrations as part of deployment, but if you can't then this works

Comment: My solution also doesn't address your entire problem. It just gives you a place where you can handle errors etc, always at the start of the program rather than tucked away in a background service. I don't have the answer to your rollback etc problems. Another reason to not do it this way is if your app is replicated, you wouldn't want all replicas trying to migrate at once which is why at deployment is the best bet. Then you don't deploy an application with a db that isn't yet compatible

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 well I think then it would be the best to remove the migration code completely. but I still don't know how to create a script like "this is the bin folder, go and search for the migration classes and run them in a single transaction. You should be able to know which migrations already have been run on this system"

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to answer without knowing your goals, but a few points worth keeping in mind:

- Try to always make your individual migrations work within a single database transaction. If something goes wrong, the database simply rolls back the transaction and you can start over once you've fixed the problem.
- If the above is not always possible, you need to ensure that you have implemented a way to safely roll back a migration.
- If anything unaccounted for goes wrong and your rollbacks don't safely reestablish the original state of the database make sure you **backup your database before you start the migration process** so that you can restore the database.